# Easiest Way to Put a Circular Frame Around a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make a cool effect for one the of the apps I'm building, and would rather not muck around with the drawRect function. Can you guys think of a simple way to put a nice circular border around a UIImage? It should look something like a round picture frame.

Here's what I'm using so far:

```
CGFloat radius = self.layer.bounds.size.width / 2;

    CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    mask.frame = self.layer.bounds;
    [mask setFillColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

    CGFloat width = self.layer.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.layer.bounds.size.height;
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, width, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, width, height - radius);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, width, height, width - radius, height, width - radius, height);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, height);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, radius);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0, radius, 0, radius, 0);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    [mask setPath:path];
    CGPathRelease(path);

    self.layer.mask = mask; 

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
```

My UIImage is encapsulated in a UIView (self is a UIView). I'm expecting it to draw a circle around my UIView.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw to an image without using a view or are you asking if it is possible to draw to an image without actually drawing to it?

Comment: I'm trying to draw a circle around my image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the best way to do it is using QuartzCore.

Basically you'd need to include the QuartzCore framework and then create a UIView to put your image in, then round it's corners and set it's clipsToBounds property to YES.

Example:

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

//More code stuff

UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
newView.clipsToBounds = YES;
newView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[newView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach that I've found is that if you want a shadow on your image you'll be in trouble because you have to clipToBounds.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about being in trouble with that.  

And that's why in my comment I say, "...create a UIView to put your image in...",  And that's not a perfect answer in some cases but it does allow you to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a mask on the layer of the UIImageView, or just set the corner radius to half the height.  In either case be sure to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.bounds.size.width / 2;
```

Example mask to make two rounded corners (change to make it a circle instead):

```
+ (void) applyTwoCornerMask: (CALayer *) layer withRadius: (CGFloat) radius {
    CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    mask.frame = layer.bounds;
    [mask setFillColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

    CGFloat width = layer.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = layer.bounds.size.height;
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, width, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, width, height - radius);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, width, height, width - radius, height, width - radius, height);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, height);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, radius);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0, radius, 0, radius, 0);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    [mask setPath:path];
    CGPathRelease(path);

    layer.mask = mask;  
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me. Here's the code: **code wont fit in comment, please check edits**

Answer (score 1):

How about the following approach:
Use a second UIImageView that is on top of the original that has the image you want framed.  This second UIImageView has a stretchable version of your picture frame image, so that your picture frame can change if the original image changes size.

Not easily reusable, but it would be simple.

You would use the stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth method of UIImage to create the stretchable version of the picture frame image.